# Tomcat processing time and time in the queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, tomcat, latency

Could someone helm me understand how exact is Tomcat processing time logged in the access logs?

Tomcat will increase connections based on demand up to `maxConnections` and spin up threads to serve requests up to `maxThreads`. Once `maxConnections` reached, new connections are placed in the queue to wait for the next available thread.

Ok, so far so good. There are two cases if a request comes and there are no free threads to serve it:

1. Current number of threads is < `maxThreads` => a new thread is spawned
2. Current number of threads = `maxThreads` => queue time

So time on the server would be equal to the processing time once a thread starts serving the request + (overhead for either spinning up a new thread or waiting for one to free up)

Is this overhead accounted for in the `processingTime` jmx metric?

In all of our environments we're observing that clients sometime report huuge latency (into the seconds) while Tomcat access logs show response time for the same request between 10ms and 100ms, and we're scratching our heads trying to understand where the remaining several seconds went.

httpstat is also reporting much larger server processing time than what we're seeing in the Tomcat metrics.

Application is Spring Boot based, if that is relevant.
Both caller and server are within the same k8s cluster & namespace. Calls are over http and on the service DNS

We enabled apache wire logs in the callers to confirm if there's a bottleneck on the caller side - apache wire logs match the reported latencies into the seconds.

httpstat is also reporting much larger server processing time than what we're seeing in the Tomcat metrics.

Tomcat server is very much underutilized (current connections keep around 60-80 / 200) and reporting processing times of a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well your intuition is correct, the processingTime does not take into account the time it stays in the queue for processing.

But the odd thing is the mention that the server is underutilized, with 60-80 threads usually used. I can only assume that you have spikes in which the load goes way past the 200 concurrent request, so the servers would need more than 200 workers to handle them.

One thing which is very worth of mentioning here is that the max number of threads does not consumes any resource. So the wording of the question is a little misleading "very much underutilized". Nothing is utilized by increasing the max number of threads, and any new worker thread will live only 60 seconds if does not have anything useful to do.

If you enable the property `server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled` (since you are on Spring Boot) you will see a few very useful extra metrics: the number of busy threads, the current threads and maximum number of threads. And it will be visible in those metrics, that the number of current threads goes up and down with the load. And as soon as the `tomcat.threads.busy` equals `tomcat.threads.config.max`, any new request goes into the queue and the timing is off in the logs and you will noticed the described behaviour.

**As a solution, as far as I can see now you have only a few options:**

- increase aggresively the max number of threads (until your hardware permits, always performance test to make sure if you get close to the limit the system does not breaks in any way, for example with OOM or any other way. As far as I know the JVM can handle up to 4000 threads as a maximum upper limit per GB of RAM with no-op threads, but of course it will be lower based on the actual memory usage inside those threads)
- Upgrade to Spring Boot 3.2 with Java 21 and virtual threads enabled. I've actually done this and it works like magic, you will never see the mentioned behaviour anymore.

**So to conclude**: the only real fix is to either use virtual threads or the reactive approach (WebFlux), but you can alleviate the symptoms by increasing the number of threads.

---